# when I click on the first item in the list it removes all items

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

when I create a mutableStateOf (true) in foreach to hide a Row and click on the first item removes all options I wanted to remove just the row that has the button inside
I tried to create a MutableState array `val visible = arrayOf <MutableState<Boolean>> ()` but it gives error what is the best way to do this within the foreach
How can I fix this error

My Code:

```
@Composable
        private fun Content(){
            Column(modifier=Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top){
                //val visibles= arrayOf<MutableState<Boolean>>()
    
                if(i.isNotEmpty()){
                    i.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
                        var quantidades by remember{ mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue(item.quantidade.toString())) }
                        var visible by remember {
                            mutableStateOf(true)
                        }
    
                        if(visible) {
                            Row(
                                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                                    modifier = Modifier
                                        .padding(bottom = 8.dp)
                                        .fillMaxWidth(100f)
                                        
    
                            ) {
                                CoilImage(
                                        data = item.photo,
                                        contentDescription = item.name,
                                        fadeIn = true,
                                        loading = {
                                            Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                                                CircularProgressIndicator(Modifier.align(Alignment.Center))
                                            }
                                        },
                                        modifier = Modifier
                                            .size(100.dp),
                                        error = {
                                            Image(
                                                    painterResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background),
                                                    contentDescription = "Error"
                                            )
                                        }
    
                                )
                                Text(
                                        text = item.name,
                                        fontSize = 15.sp,
                                        modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 20.dp)
                                )
    //                Text(text=item.count.toString())
    //                Text(text=item.id.toString())
    
    
                                TextField(
                                        value = quantidades,
                                        onValueChange = {
                                            quantidades = it
                                            //_addUserState.value = _addUserState.value?.copy(name = it)
                                        },
                                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
                                        colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                                                focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                                                unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                                                disabledIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent
    
                                        ),
                                        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                                                keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number,
                                                imeAction = ImeAction.Next
                                        ),
                                        modifier = Modifier
                                            .width(50.dp)
                                            .height(50.dp)
    
                                )
                                Column(
                                        modifier = Modifier
                                            .fillMaxWidth(100f)
                                            .padding(5.dp), horizontalAlignment = Alignment.End
                                ) {
    
    
                                    Button(
                                            onClick = { visible=onVisible(visible,item) },
                                            modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 20.dp)
                                    ) {
                                        Icon(
                                                Icons.Default.Delete,
                                                stringResource(id = R.string.deletar)
                                        )
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
    
                    }
                }else{
                    Text(text= stringResource(id = R.string.sem_carrinho), fontSize = 15.sp)
                }
                
            }
        }
    
        private fun onVisible(visible: Boolean, item:ShoppingCart):Boolean{
            counter.value--
    
            i.remove(item)
            return !visible
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I copied and pasted your code and I'm not able to run it.
But have you tried to use a key for each `visible` state?

```
var visible by remember(index) { mutableStateOf(true) }
```